# Python 3: won't print anything for this string obejct

Tags: python-3.x, string, ascii

I have a `text` (that's a string with capital letters) and I am mapping letters to other letters.
Anyway, my problem is that I can't see anything being printed when I do `print(f(a, b, text))`  (with some proper values of course).
What's strange is that the inner print I put for debugging reasons seems to work : I get messages like: `A was mapped to G` and so on.
I also checked the type `print(type(m))` and got  `<class 'str'>`.
I can't see why this string appears to be empty.
In the documentation `chr()` has return type `char` , and I simply do concatenation with  `+=` . Can you help?

```py
def f(a, b, text):
    d = {}
    for i in range(26):
        d[ (a*i + b) % 26] = i
    print(d)
    message = " "
    for s in text:
        message += chr(d[ord(s)-65])
        print(chr(d[ord(s)-65] +65 ),  " was mapped to", s)
    return message

m = f(20, 7, "LFJFJGHG")
print(m)
```

Comment: This code will likely produce KeyError. All characters are not being mapped. And you're concatenating characters with ASCII values of around 10-20.  That's why you're message appears empty string. Try running this code in IDLE and instead of `>> print(m)`, just try `>> m`.

Comment: @0x5961736972 it does not produce a key error. Only capital english are inserted as messages (26 letters). I will try in the IDLE though

Comment: Ok, I just copied the function in my Shell, it says `KeyError: 6`

Comment: This function cannot possibly work for all inputs, since `len(d) < 26` if `gcd(a, 26) > 1 `.

Comment: @ekhumoro assume that gcd(a, 26) ==1

Comment: @tonythestark No - that assumption is wrong, because in your example `gcd(20, 26) == 2` and `len(d) == 13`, so it's a coin-flip as to whether you will get key-errors. What is your exact reasoning for constructing `d` in the way that you do?